# OpenLayers map shows an extra tile on top of map

Tags: java, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, cordova, openlayers

I have an `Windows Phone 8` app made with `PhoneGap` framework to show a map of `OpenLayers`. Sometimes, although very rarely, I **surf between views** (`jQuery Mobile` is used) and suddenly when I am back on Map **it shows an extra tile on the center of map**. Tile is as wide as the map and starts some 20% before top and ends some 20% from bottom. It does disappear only when restarting the app.

I am trying to show up the phenomenon on dev mode of Google on browser, but so far no success.

No error is shown on console of wp8 sdk, I was testing it on device connected to visual studio.

**What may cause that thing and could it be fixed somehow?**

***edit1:** It may be possible I trigger a swipe event while moving the screen fast and that may make the `Openlayers` in error state.*

Comment: possible answer is around this SO post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654238/can-i-disable-ie10-history-swipe-gesture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First try:**

I added this line:

```
   -ms-scroll-chaining: chained;
```

to the div containing the map.

I used [jQuery / HTML5 / gwt app for WP8 (Lumia 920) device: vertical css scroll fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943291/jquery-html5-gwt-app-for-wp8-lumia-920-device-vertical-css-scroll-fix) to attach another things to same place, so I added it there.

**UPDATE**

This was not the fix, problem stayed. See below the correct answer:

**The real answer:**

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/929 tells this is known issue of openlayers, that is already fixed in the latest version.

**So, please update version of OpenLayers!**

Comment: I'll accept the answer, when the "accept your own question" ban period is over.

Comment: Seems to be OL bug or sth, this setting is actually the default. I just could not reproduce bug for a while and this seemed to help. Original idea was to have the 'none' selected, but it closed the whole app on that error event. I tested the opposite and whilst no error came easily, I thought this was what I wanted. Apparently it was not.

Comment: This map thing is unrelated to the swipe, it is another thing, that is partially fixed with the original setting. Actual problem solved with that fix: app does not close compeletedly when such misbehaving event is triggered.