# Disable web page navigation on swipe(back and forward)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

On a Windows phone, in IE users can go back and forward by swiping on the screen if the swipe is coming from the edge. This OS level functionality is hampering my webpage's UX.

Is there any js or css which can disable that? Some hack would also do.

A snapshot from windowsphone's website:
[image]

Here is the link to the reference page: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/basics/gestures-swipe-pan-and-stretch

Please note that I still need touchaction enabled for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with `-ms-scroll-chaining: none;` CSS param?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13709150/1540570

Comment: Is it correct, that there is no correct answer?

Answer (score 23):

You Should Try this solution in two way :

**1) CSS only fix for Chrome/Firefox**

```
 html, body {
    overscroll-behavior-x: none;
}
```

**2) JavaScript fix for Safari**

```
if (window.safari) {
  history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
  window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      history.go(1);
  };
}
```

Over time, Safari will implement [overscroll-behavior-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior-x) and we'll be able to remove the JS hack

Possible duplicate of [iOS 7 - is there a way to disable the swipe back and forward functionality in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889666/ios-7-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-swipe-back-and-forward-functionality-in-sa)

Comment: Works great in Firefox/Chrome, thanks! 

I can't get either the CSS (which MDN says is now supported) or the JS to work in modern Safari.  Might be me being stupid though ...

Answer (score 4):

Copy and paste this JavaScript:

```
var xPos = null;
var yPos = null;
window.addEventListener( "touchmove", function ( event ) {
    var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ];
    oldX = xPos;
    oldY = yPos;
    xPos = touch.pageX;
    yPos = touch.pageY;
    if ( oldX == null && oldY == null ) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if ( Math.abs( oldX-xPos ) > Math.abs( oldY-yPos ) ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
} );
```

If you want it minified, copy and paste this:

`var xPos=null;var yPos=null;window.addEventListener("touchmove",function(event){var touch=event.originalEvent.touches[0];oldX=xPos;oldY=yPos;xPos=touch.pageX;yPos=touch.pageY;if(oldX==null && oldY==null){return false;}else{if(Math.abs(oldX-xPos)>Math.abs(oldY-yPos)){event.preventDefault();return false;}}});`

Comment: disables scroll as well

Comment: This measures if you swipe in the horizontal direction more than the vertical direction, so it shouldn't disable scroll unless you scroll crooked!

Comment: "Copy and paste this" is not a good annotation for a code snippet. Some kind of description of what it's doing would be better.

Comment: It's pretty bad, but "Copy and paste this minified code" is so much worse

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/vidhill/pen/zvoLZO) by David Hill.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("container"); //area we don't want touch drag

var defaultPrevent=function(e){e.preventDefault();}
elem.addEventListener("touchstart", defaultPrevent);
elem.addEventListener("touchmove" , defaultPrevent);
```

I actually think this is a cool way to build objects too.

Answer (score 1):

How about preventing the default action of the swipe event. Somewhere in your document.ready add (note I've included the document.ready in this example, only the function needs to be added):

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('touchmove',function(e){e.preventDefault();});
});`

In this case I believe the event is called 'touchmove'you may need to extend this to also ignore default behavior of touchstart/touchend but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: That disables scrolling as well, though.

Comment: You could store the last touch position and just determine if the offset is more vertical or more horizontal, say you had point (1,1); if the next touch move was (3,2) you'd know the user moved more in the horizontal direction than vertical, in which case you would call `preventDefault()`, and otherwise allow it. Here's a similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278087/determine-vertical-direction-of-a-touchmove)

Answer (score 0):

This is also a problem for Mac users who have configured swipe-left to navigate backwards. You can't disable this setting, but you can prompt the user to confirm that they intended to navigate away https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload.

Answer (score -5):

```
*{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

The result is to completely deactivate any touch events

Comment: This is only available on safari, and only prevents the callout from displaying rather than preventing touch gestures - the callout is a popup which provides information about a link when you touch and hold it.