# Angularjs app going to back page on left swipe

Tags: angularjs, rest

My angular js spa is going to previous page on swiping it left and to forward page on right in windows mobile browser IE .I havent implemented this and cant figure out why this is happening .i want to disable this.I have a back button in my app which uses history.back()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I disable IE10 history swipe gesture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654238/can-i-disable-ie10-history-swipe-gesture)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a angular feature but a feature of the browser itself. Check this question for how to disable this with css: [Can I disable IE10 history swipe gesture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654238/can-i-disable-ie10-history-swipe-gesture)

Comment: Can you share the link

Comment: Sorry, forgot to link it. Here you go :)